# WUSA syntax issue, /norestart

Tags: windows-7, command-line

I am attempting to use this syntax:

> wusa.exe "IE11-Windows6.1-KB2929437-x64.msu" /norestart

But it simply pops up with the WUSA help box, like it doesn't understand my syntax.

I've tried a full path or without quotes, same issue. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1):

#### It doesn't understand my syntax.

```
wusa.exe "IE11-Windows6.1-KB2929437-x64.msu" /norestart
```

Look at the help box that pops up.

> `/norestart`
>
> When **combined** with `/quiet` installer will NOT initiate reboot.

Try the following command:

```
wusa.exe {path}\IE11-Windows6.1-KB2929437-x64.msu /quiet /norestart
```

Where `{path}` is the full path to `IE11-Windows6.1-KB2929437-x64.msu`

---

#### Description of the Windows Update Standalone Installer in Windows

> You can use the following switches together with Wusa.exe.
>
> - `/norestart`    Prevents `Wusa.exe` from restarting the computer.
>
>   The `/norestart` switch is ignored if the `/quiet` switch is not
>     present.
>
>   If you run Wusa.exe together with these two switches, you must
>     manually  restart the operating system after the installation is
>     complete if the installation requires you to restart the computer.
>
>   For example, if the `Windows6.0-KB934307-x86.msu` file is in the
>     `D:\934307` folder, type the following command at a command prompt to
>     install the update package:
>
>   wusa.exe D:\934307\Windows6.0-KB934307-x86.msu /quiet /norestart

Source [Description of the Windows Update Standalone Installer in Windows](https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/kb/934307)